# Preferred way to make script directly executable

Tags: linux, unix, ffmpeg

I can run ffmpeg by executing the executable file in ~/bin:

```
$ ~/bin/ffmpeg
```

To be able to just do `$ ffmpeg`, one option would be to create an alias in my `'~.bash_profile` or `$ sudo ln -s ~/bin/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg`. Is there a better way to do this, so that I can use `ffmpeg` in scripts and that command will be recognized?

Comment: What's your distro? Or will this be used on several different distros? Usually the distro doesn't matter, but in some cases they offer various default `PATH` locations (such as Ubuntu with `~/bin` being declared in `~/.profile`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest either copy or link `~/bin/ffmpeg` into `/usr/local/bin`
This is usually on your `PATH`, you can check with

```
echo $PATH
```

Using it in scripts depends on how the script is executed, and by what user. One case needs extra care is `cron` which uses a very basic `PATH` variable.
In general I suggest to use full paths in scripts to avoid problems, instead of relying on `PATH` or aliases.